# Работа с SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

У меня есть 2 таблицы, хочу добавить по строке в каждую и передать изменения в БД. Пользуюсь при этом SqlCommandBuilder. Вот мой код:

```
 string connectionString = @"Data Source=WKS456\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers;Select * FROM Employees";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            DataTable customers = ds.Tables[0];
            DataTable employees = ds.Tables[1];

            // добавим новую строку в первую таблицу:

            DataRow newRow = customers.NewRow();
            newRow["FName"] = "x";
            newRow["LName"] = "x";
            newRow["Address1"] = "x";
            newRow["City"] = "x";
            newRow["Phone"] = "x";
            customers.Rows.Add(newRow);

            // добавим новую строку во вторую таблицу:

            DataRow newRow1 = employees.NewRow();
            newRow1["EmployeeID"] = 101;
            newRow1["FName"] = "x";
            newRow1["LName"] = "x";
            newRow1["MName"] = "x";
            newRow1["Salary"] = 111;
            newRow1["PriorSalary"] = 111;
            newRow1["HireDate"] = "9999 / 12 / 31";
            newRow1["ManagerEmpID"] = 5;
            employees.Rows.Add(newRow1);

            //Создаю SqlCommandBuilder:

        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(ds);
```

Далее наблюдаю странную работу, а именно: изменения отправляются только в одну таблицу, причем в первую (customers). Во второй(employees)-тишина. Пробовал закомментить добалвение строки в первую таблицу, т.е. оставил только вторую - всё отработало - во второй таблице (employees)- строка появилась. Но почему не работает на 2 одновременно таблицы? я пробовал разные перегрузки adapter.Update(...) - но ничего не помогает.

Comment: а в чем проблема выполнить их по очереди

Comment: и выполнить как обычной запрос.

Comment: вообще лучше используй Entity Framework в связке c sqlite

Comment: @Санитариум, по очереди всмысле 2 раза использовать adapter.Update()? Так пробовал тоже - не получается. обычный запрос не интересен, хочу научиться работать с sqlcomandbuilder. Entity обязательно изучу, но позже :)

Comment: Вcмысле написать запрос руками insert into и потом если запрос выполнится то уже обновить UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы создали экземпляр адаптера этой строкой:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
```

у него было задано свойство `SelectCommand`, которое используется при получении данных из БД методом `Fill`.

Метод `Update` использует в своей работе свойство `UpdateCommand`. Если вы его не задали каким-либо образом, то это свойство равно `null`.

Нужно либо вручную его задать:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ...");
```

либо сгенерировать автоматически с помощью `SqlCommandBuilder`.

Этой строкой вы создали экземпляр билдера:

```
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
```

Далее нужно либо вызвать его метод, чтобы сгенерировать sql-код и назначить эту команду соответствующему свойству:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
```

либо, если это свойство ещё не задано, то при первом вызове метода `adapter.Update` билдер будет использован автоматически.

---

Собственно, всё выше написанное лишь объяснение принципов работы, а ответ на вопрос вот:

Проверил работу билдера на sql-коде, содержащем два запроса `select`. Он генерирует `update` только по первому селекту.

Поэтому либо используйте два вызова подряд, либо задавайте код обновления вручную.

Comment: спасибо, что разъяснили. В случае, если я хочу использовать два вызова подряд, то я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно использовать два разных адаптера и, соответственно, 2 датасета?

Comment: @Mikhail - датасет использовать один, потому что изменения сохранены в нём. А вот адаптеров, вероятно, лучше сделать два.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться. Действительно, всё как Вы сказали, если два Selecta подряд в одном адаптере, то билдер генерит UpdateCommand почему-то только по первому selectу, т.е. UpdateCommand для второго selecta нужно прописывать вручную. Если selecta два и по каждому свой адаптер, то тогда билдер генерит правильный UpdateCommand для каждого selecta. В обоих случаях проверил и убедился в этом вызовом текста команды (commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText)