# C# Как сохранить изменения в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Сейчас у меня есть DataGridView, в котором отображается 1 из связанных таблиц .mdb
Есть фрагмент кода:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.studPerfDataSet.Students);
}
```

Я пытался сделать кнопку и вставить туда следующий код:

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.studentsTableAdapter.Update(this.studPerfDataSet.Students);
}
```

Из этого ничего не вышло, т.к. после нажатия на кнопку я получал сообщение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Для обновления требуется действительный UpdateCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с измененными строками."

Comment: [Обновление источников данных с объектами DataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/904478/184217